# Send TCP response after SQL Service Broker completes its operations

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, response, tcplistener

My application currently listens to a TCP port and parses the inbound data to xml. The problem I have is that the application needs to send back a response containing a different set of xml which is created by a service broker application. I am VEEERY new to network application programming and don't have a solid understanding of the way the inbound/outbound is handled. At this point everything works as it should, but the only response I can seem to generate is "Last message from client - " + an echo of what was sent. Here is the code for my TCP server...

```
public static void ReceivePortMessages()
{
    IPAddress ip = Dns.GetHostEntry("sctest.com").AddressList[0];
    TcpListener serverSocket = new TcpListener(ip, 8080);
    int requestCount = 0;
    TcpClient clientSocket = default(TcpClient);
    serverSocket.Start();
    Debug.Print(" >> Server Started");
    clientSocket = serverSocket.AcceptTcpClient();
    Debug.Print(" >> Accept connection from client");
    requestCount = 0;

    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            requestCount = requestCount + 1;
            NetworkStream networkStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
            byte[] bytesFrom = new byte[10025];
            networkStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, (int)clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);
            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();
            string dataFromClient = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesFrom);
            dataFromClient = dataFromClient.Substring(0, dataFromClient.IndexOf("\0"));
            Debug.Print(" >> Data from client - " + dataFromClient);
            string serverResponse = "Last Message from client" + dataFromClient;
            Byte[] sendBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(serverResponse);
            networkStream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length);
            networkStream.Flush();
            Debug.Print(" >> " + serverResponse);

            try
            {
                XmlDocument xm = new XmlDocument();
                xm.LoadXml(string.Format("<root>{0}</root>", dataFromClient));
                XmlElement root = xm.DocumentElement;
                string rootName = root.FirstChild.Name;
                RouteInboundXML(rootName, dataFromClient, sw);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.Print("Data provided does not match any predefined XML schemas; it will be ignored.");
            }
        }
        catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException ex)
        {
            Debug.Print("Remote client disconnected.");
            clientSocket.Close();
            serverSocket.Stop();
            ReceivePortMessages();
            return;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.Print(ex.ToString());
            clientSocket.Close();
            serverSocket.Stop();
            ReceivePortMessages();
            return;
        }
        Debug.Print(" >> exit");
    }
}
```

What I really need to happen is the part of the code that sends a response, to send a response AFTER the service broker pics up the xml data, modifies it and will send a new xml string back.

```
private void PingReplyDependency()
{
    try
    {
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        if (!isPermitted())
        {
            return;
        }
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(dbUSApp))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = PING_AWAIT;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Notification = null;
            con.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (dr.HasRows)
                {
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        PingReply ping = new PingReply();
                        ping.REPLY_CODE = dr["REPLY_CODE"].ToString();
                        WriteXMLFile<PingReply>(ping, string.Format(@"XML\PingSend{0}.xml", ping.TRAN_ID));

                        string rowPointer = dr["RowPointer"].ToString();
                        using (SqlConnection conInsert = new SqlConnection(dbP3USDApp))
                        using (SqlCommand cmdInsert = NonQueryCommand("[SP_DO_Xml]", conInsert,
                            new SqlParameter("@RowPointer", rowPointer)))
                        {
                            conInsert.Open();
                            cmdInsert.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ErrorLog.Write("Notification System", ex.ToString(), "SystemAvailabilityReply", Environment.UserName, "Failed Ping.");
    }
}
```

If more info or clarity is needed, just let me know. I tried to only post what I felt was essential, but I may have missed an important piece from an outside perspective. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The receiving is deeply broken. You need to deal with the fact that `Read` can return as little as one byte at a time. Either use a loop to drain what's incoming or directly pass the NetworkStream to the XML lib so that it can pull the XML.

Comment: @usr Could you elaborate a little bit. Almost every example of this process I could find looked like this. Could you show me some code to at least get started in that direction?

Answer (score -1):

TCP is stream based. That means that there is no notation of application messages in TCP. All TCP understand is that it's sending a stream of bytes where there is no seperation between messages.

For you that means that a message can be divided so that you have to use multiple `socket.Receive()` to get a complete message, or that you get several complete messages in one `socket.Receive()`.

Therefore you have to figure out some way to know where a message begins or ends. Typically one uses a length header or a message delimiter.

If you do not want to take care of everything yourself you can use my Apache licensed networking library: http://griffinframework.net/doc/networking

Comment: The 'substring.indexof("\0")' finds the end of my message as it on the end of every semt string. Is that what you are referring to? These messages are all predefined templates too.

Comment: you are assuming that `networkStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, (int)clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);`  will include a complete message. That's incorrect. You should also check the return value from `Read` as `0` means that the remote end point disconnected.